# Problems with Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sublime-text

I just installed ubuntu 14.04, and have, sadly, experienced some problems. One of them is with sublime text 3. It worked fine earlier today, but when I started the computer again, it was like this. I have tried to open and close it, and add projects, but this is all I get, and I can't make much sense of it or use it. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether it is correct or not: remove and then reinstall sublime text 3

Answer (score 0):

I removed the theme, and it seems like that solved the problem.